# SQLAlchemy add vs add_all

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out when to use `session.add` and when to use `session.add_all` with SQLAlchemy.

Specifically, I don't understand the downsides of using `add_all`. It can do everything that `add` can do, so why not just always use it? There is no mention of this in the SQLalchemy [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session).

Comment: Looking at the [code](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/640cd8a70f8a664b7834c5f74ec322fdea644043/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L2471), there isn't any difference. `add_all` calls `add` n no. of times.

Comment: I think the reason `add_all` and `add` co-exist is for the same reason `append` and `extend` exist for a list. You could achieve `extend` functionality by calling `append` multiple no. of times but `extend` is definitely optimized for adding multiple elements at once and also saves us from writing a loop for such a trivial task. Even if it's not optimized now, may it will be in future.

Comment: Good point @shiva. I guess theoretically the same logic applies - we could always use `extend` but we don't in practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have one new record to add, then use `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add()` but if you have multiple records then use `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add_all()`. There's not really a significant difference, except the API of the first method is for a single instance whereas the second is for multiple instances.  Is that a big difference? No. It's just convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about the same and as mentioned by others, there is no real difference. However, I would like to add that using `add` in a loop, instead of using `add_all` allows you to be more fine grained regarding exception handling. Passing a list of mapped class instances to `add_all` will cause a rollback for all instances if, for example, one of these objects violates a constraint (e.g., unique). I prefer to decouple my data logic from my service logic and decide what to do with instances not stored in the service layer by returning them from my data layer. However, I think it depends on how you are handling exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

As per the implementation of add_all() which is also making an call to add method in a forloop. So even I agree that there no much difference in both.
[image]

However if you have a requirement of autoincrement and PK/FK relationship then we can't make use of add_all() method in such usecases, but add() method will be handy there.